# Parse Notifications

Tags: parse-platform

Question about Parse and notifications:

What technique should be used to detect a change in data in a Parse object. i.e. Parse objects are not KVO compliant, nor do they notify 'listeners' when their properties change. How would say, a multi-user app sharing a data set know to get new data?

It's a Mac OS X app, so Push Notifications are not supported (not that it would be a good option anyway)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cronjob to check periodically if the data has changed.

For example you can do this by writing a script that checks the data every 5 minutes. 
If there is data that has been updated in the last 5 minutes, do something with this.
Make sure your think about writing a decent script in order to avoid double alerts (you can maintain a temporary log for example to list the latest changes in order to avoid duplicates).

Comment: A polling technique would work but that seems like a lot of unnecessary bandwidth usage. Thanks for the reply.